# Does Django have a Windows 7 Installer? I couldn't find one and theres little mention of Windows

Tags: django

I would like to learn Django on Windows.  Is this possible?  I've Googled and can't seem to find a page that even explains this is possible, let alone an install or step-by-step.

Comment: Where are you having trouble? Nothing in the [official installation docs](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/topics/install/) is incompatible with Windows, and plenty of people develop happily there.

Comment: I'm not sure about 2011, but in 2016 it seems like a good idea to install with pip. It's easy, and you can also easily install any django packages later on.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

1. Download and install Python 2.7.1 for Windows:
    http://www.python.org/ftp/python/2.7.1/python-2.7.1.msi
2. Download Django package and unpack:
    http://www.djangoproject.com/download/1.2.5/tarball/
    (you need a tool like 7Zip to unpack the tar archive, Windows can't deal with it)
3. Open terminal and setup.py from the folder where Django has been upacked:
   `C:\download\Django-1.2.5> c:\Python27\python.exe setup.py install`
4. Go and start working through the tutorial.

Note: You'll find the django scripts in the site-packages folder in your Python installation folder: `C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\django\bin`

Comment: Thank you!  That's EXACTLY what I was looking for.   As I guessing it's not so straightforward and easy (a dedicated Windows install).

Comment: django versions less than 1.3 will get an error "no modules staticfiles". Get the latest at https://www.djangoproject.com/download/

Answer (score 5):

Alternatively you could use the [BitNami DjangoStack](http://bitnami.org/stack/djangostack) (disclaimer: I'm a BitNami developer). The stack already includes Python, Django and you can also select to install MySQL and/or PostgreSQL. It is a free installer that in a few click allows you to have your environment for developing Django applications ready. It is self-contained and install all the dependencies you need and the more common python modules. Also it will not interfere with your current environment.