# Django 1.5.1 installation issue in windows 7

Tags: django

I would like to learn Django on Windows.I have installed python 2.7.I am unaware of installing Django. I have googled a lot,but didn't understand properly.I referred [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5155317/does-django-have-a-windows-7-installer-i-couldnt-find-one-and-theres-little-me) ,But i didn't understood the third point in the accepted answer. I have installed python in `c:\`.Also django also in `c:\`.Please help me.I have extracted the django
[image]

Comment: He means 'cmd', terminal is a mac thing

Comment: @Hedde That i understood,But {C:\download\Django-1.2.5> c:\Python27\python.exe setup.py install} means I should write the code like this inside django

Comment: You can also install it by microsoft web platform installer if you have visual studio

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I always used this link and everything worked like a charm (I didn't install iPython and didn't go through step 3):
http://www.swegler.com/becky/blog/2011/08/27/python-django-mysql-on-windows-7-part-i-getting-started/

Answer (score 0):

The 3rd point is where Django gets installed, if you are stuck on that point, you have not installed it yet.

You need to extract django to a folder, `cd` to that folder and run `python setup.py install`

The reason that the other answer has `C:\download\Django-1.2.5>` is that they extracted django to that directory and `c:\Python27\python.exe` because on windows, you need to reboot in order for path modifications to take effect. So instead, they are accessing the python executable directly with no need to reboot.

---

To check if you have successfully installed django you can do the following (yes, will work for windows)

```
(virtualenv)[root@localhost ~]# python
Python 2.7.4 (default, Apr  8 2013, 14:05:01) 
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-3)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import django
>>> django.get_version()
'1.5.1'
```

open up cmd, type `python` (as long as you added it to your path)
then type `import django`
followed by `django.get_version()`

If you did it successfully, there will be no import errors and you will see the version of django that is installed.

Comment: I have attached the image.Please check it

Comment: @AnazA Open `cmd`, not `powershell` and do what I said. Your image does not show you running `python setup.py install`

Comment: I have installed python earlier.I have installed django and pip according to matino answer.

Comment: @AnazA `python setup.py install` does NOT install python. When run inside the extracted django folder, it installs DJANGO.

Comment: Ok.thanks.I have installed django by this way.so i can run django now rite??

Comment: @AnazA You don't "run django" it is a framework. You write apps using django and run/interact with them using the management commands. See my edit to check if you installed it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to suggest some extra steps for you that will be invaluable in the long run. First, use [virtualenv](http://www.virtualenv.org/en/latest/) for your development. This lets you keep several separate Python environments on your machine, each tuned to the projects they're running. Keeping all your projects in a virtualenv also means, if you do something that breaks that environment's Python installation, the rest of your projects are unaffected. I use Linux so I've never installed virtualenv on Windows but [this tutorial](https://zignar.net/2012/06/17/install-python-on-windows/) seems sensible.

Virtualenv has a package called [`pip`](http://www.pip-installer.org/en/latest/) installed automatically. Pip is a Python package installer. Using that, getting Django installed and set up is as easy as typing `pip install Django` at a command prompt. It also has lots of other really useful features for controlling and backing up Python environments that you can find in its documentation.